# Unit testing with Ruby

Tags: ruby

In my root directory I have two files,

> test_wordplay.rb

and

> wordplay.rb

Inside test_wordplay.rb:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'wordplay'

class TestWordPlay < MiniTest::Unit
end
```

But when I run

```
ruby test_wordplay.rb
```

I get:

```
usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- wordplay (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from test_wordplay.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: why `ruby ruby test_wordplay.rb` not `ruby test_wordplay.rb`

Comment: @Priti Simply a typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
require 'wordplay'
```

try

```
require_relative 'wordplay'
```

This will make Ruby look for the file in the same directory as the file the `require_relative` is in.

Comment: +1, personally I prefer knowing exactly what my include path is, but I admit I do this sometimes :/ The caveat is that you can't separate your tests from "real" code this way unless you start using relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

```
ruby -I. test_wordplay.rb
```

You need to explicitly set the include directory.

Comment: This is the more standard solution.